# Most efficient way to count the number of duplicate elements in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, hashmap, hashtable

Imagine we have an array of students:

> Students: Ben Sam ...

Every student has a group of books at home:

Books:

- Sam  A B C D
- Ben  D E F
- Ryan A D G D

So in PHP, the $students data structure looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Joe Smith
            [books] => Array
                (
                    [0] => A
                    [1] => B
                    [2] => C
                )

        )

)
```

We want to count how many times  A has been repeated and who owns A B and C etc. 
One way to do it in php is to do this:

```
if (sizeof($potential_entries) > 0) :
  for ($j = 0, $potentialsize = sizeof($potential_entries); $j < $potentialsize; ++$j)     {
    for ($k = 0, $listsize = sizeof($student_book); $k < $listsize; ++$k) {
      if ($student_book[$k] == $potential_entry[$k]) :
        $match = 1;
        $student_book[$k]['like_count']++;
       endif;
    }
  }
```

This is not very efficient we rather want a map structure or a hashtable, Does php has those structures like perl? or do we have to manually build them.
Edit:
 I can see in the PHP that we have associative array? Can you please give an example of that could not find it in the documentation.
for sam:

```
var_dump($potential_entry):

[0]=>array(2) { ["name"]=> string(1) "A" ["id"]=> string(11) "1348"}
[1]=>array(2) { ["name"]=> string(1) "B" ["id"]=> string(11) "1483"}
[2]=>array(2) { ["name"]=> string(1) "C" ["id"]=> string(11) "13"}
[3]=>array(2) { ["name"]=> string(1) "D" ["id"]=> string(11) "1174"}
```

That is for Sam, for the rest we have the same structure. so sam is array and books is an array and sam has an array of books.
In this example

- D count=3 sam ben ryan
- A count=2 sam ryan
- etc...

Comment: I do not understand, PHP has associative array, that is another name for a map...

Comment: can you please clarify with an example/hints ...I can see associative arrays in php but I am not sure how to represent my lists as that.

Comment: I mean how can i push and pop to a hash array in php

Comment: `sizeof` could be replaced with `count` I think or if `$potential_entries` is always an array, then just `if ( $potential_entries )` should check it for emptiness.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `var_dump($potential_entries)` ?

Comment: So how exactly are you structuring the data right now? A students array with books subarray?

Comment: Exactly, so sam is array and books is an array and sam has an array of books.

Comment: @MajicJohnson - you'll get better answers if you show your data structures as code blocks.  I was just guessing as to how you represented things when I answered.

Comment: the best possibility if dealing with a large array is to use a non comparison ordering algorithm such as Counting sort or Radix that runs on a max O(n) instead of the O(n^2) / omega(nlogn) people have suggested.

Comment: @ScottWilson I am not quit sure what do you mean with code blocks...Do you mean the formatting feature code block?

Comment: @MajicJohnson - I have updated the question with an example print_r of (what I think is) your data structure.  Please correct as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $students as an array, and each entry in this array has an array of books which is called books

```
$books = array(); 
for ($i = 0, $count = sizeof($students); $i++) {
   foreach ($student[$i]['books'] as $book) { 
      if (isset($books[$book])) { 
          $books[$book]++; 
      } else { 
          $books[$book] = 1;
      }
   }
}
```

Then after this, any $books entry whose count is > 1 is a duplicate, i.e.

```
foreach ($books as $key => $value) { 
   if ($value) > 1) { 
        echo "Book " . $key . " is a duplicate (" . $value . ")"; 
   }
}
```

Comment: the outer `for` could be a `foreach`, too

Comment: @cyperhable - absolutely.  I assumed there was a numeric index, but if not, foreach would be the way to go.

Comment: @ScottWilson I did not quite understand this line:  if (isset($books[$book])) { 
          $books[$book]++; 
      } else { 
          $books[$book] = 1;
      }

Comment: what does isset($books[$book]) do?

Comment: $books is an associative array, and you need to check if the index in question has been set already.

Answer (score 1):

```
$aFullCount = array(); // in this array you will have results of all characters count.
$aCondition = array("A", "B"); // set condition you need to count down here.
$aConditionMatch = array(); // in here you will have all users ids who matched your A + B
if ($aUsers){
    foreach ($aUsers as $sUserKey=>$aOneUser){
        $aForCondition = array();
        if ($aPotentialEntries){
            foreach ($aPotentialEntries as $aOnePotentialEntry){
                $aForCondition[] = $aOnePotentialEntry["name"];
                if (!isset($aFullCount[$aOnePotentialEntry["name"]]))
                    $aFullCount[$aOnePotentialEntry["name"]] = 1;
                else
                    $aFullCount[$aOnePotentialEntry["name"]]++;
            }
        }

        $aConditionCheck = array_intersect($aForCondition, $aCondition);
        if (!array_diff($aConditionCheck, $aCondition))
            $aConditionMatch[] = $sUserKey;
    }
}
```